# Functional testing with grunt-webdriver, mocha and chai-as-promised

Tags: selenium, gruntjs, mocha.js, webdriver-io, chai-as-promised

I'm trying to build a functional testing system to verify our web site is behaving correctly for our users. I have cobbled together a bunch of Node.js modules and helpers in an attempt to get a framework that provides simple, concise tests without a heap of nested function callbacks and I believe promises can provide that, so my `package.json` file looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "chai-as-promised": "^4.3.0",
  "grunt": "^0.4.5",
  "grunt-webdriver": "^0.4.8"
}
```

My `Gruntfile.js` looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    webdriver: { // for use with webdriver.io
      options: {
        desiredCapabilities: {
          browserName: 'phantomjs' // No Xvfb required
        }
      },
      chrome: {
        tests: ['chrome/*.js'],
        options: {
          desiredCapabilities: {
            browserName: 'chrome'
          }
        }
      },
    },
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-webdriver');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['webdriver']);
};
```

And finally my test case in `chrome/login.js` looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var chai = require('chai'),
    chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised'),
    assert;

chaiAsPromised.transferPromiseness = browser.transferPromiseness;
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
assert = chai.assert;

describe('login test', function () {
    it('verifies user can log in', function(done) {
        browser
            .url('https://localhost/')
            .setValue('#userauth_username','foo')
            .setValue('#userauth_password',"password")
            .submitForm('#form_users_login')
            .then(function(){
                browser.getText('#auth-user-id', function(err, value){
                    console.log(value);
                });
                assert.becomes(browser.getText('#auth-user-id'), 'foo');
            })//.call(done);
    });
});
```

When I run `grunt webdriver:chrome` on the command line, I see it start up Chrome and log into the website. The 'auth-user-id' span is correctly displaying the user's id after logging in but for some reason `browser.getText()` is not returning it and the test is therefore failing. I have tried adding a `.pause(100)` after the `.submitForm()` to give me time to interact with the page in Chrome so I know it is a problem in the test case.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the best and most succinct way of doing what I want. I'm not sure I need `chai-as-promised` yet but maybe I'll move the login function to an included file and use chai-as-promised to assert that the promised login has occurred before entering the tests.

'use strict';

```
var chai = require('chai'),
    chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised'),
    assert,
    expect;

chaiAsPromised.transferPromiseness = browser.transferPromiseness;
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
assert = chai.assert;
expect = chai.expect;

describe('login test', function () {

    it('verifies user can log in', function(done) {

        browser
            .url('https://localhost/')
            .setValue('#userauth_username','foo')
            .setValue('#userauth_password',"password")
            .submitForm('#form_users_login')
            .waitForExist('#auth-user-id')
            .getText('#auth-user-id')
            .then(function(text){
                //console.log('Username: ' + text);
                assert.equal(text, 'foo');
            })
            .saveScreenshot('out.png')
            .call(done)

    });

    it('should not display logincontrols after login', function(done){

        browser
            .isVisible('#logincontrols')
            .then(function(bool){
                expect(bool).to.be.false;
            })
            .call(done)

    });

    it('should display loggedin section after login', function(done){

        browser
            .isVisible('#loggedin')
            .then(function(bool){
                expect(bool).to.be.true;
            })
            .call(done)

    });

});
```

and for completeness, this is what I see on the output:

```
# grunt webdriver:chrome
Running "webdriver:chrome" (webdriver) task


  login test
    ✓ verifies user can log in (7691ms)
    ✓ should not display logincontrols after login (70ms)
    ✓ should display loggedin section after login (58ms)


  3 passing (8s)


Done, without errors.
```